# Constructing a metric for a metrizable space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am an electrical engineering PhD student, not a formally educated mathematician.
I could prove that the main space I am using in my dissertation is metrizable (using Urysohn's metrization conditions) given a topology that captures an interesting notion of neighborhood from our perspective.

It would be of great operational help if a metric can be constructed that induces the same topology. I wonder if there is a general method (or even just a list of examples from which I can extrapolate to my specific case) to construct such a metric (if at all possible).

You can think of that topological space as a space of functions f: P --> S, where P can be ***any*** enumerably infinite partially ordered set (which may not be the same for all functions in that space) and S is a ***fixed*** enumerably infinite set. ***This is the space of so-called partially ordered multisets (or pomsets)***.

The topology is defined as follows:
A set is open if it can be written as the set of ***all infinite extensions*** of a set of ***finite*** pomsets.

**Some definitions**:

A pomset is finite if its underlying poset is finite.

An infinite pomset ***u*** is an ***extension*** of a finite pomset ***w*** (or ***w*** is a ***prefix*** of ***u***) if the poset underlying ***w*** is (order-isomorphic to) a subset of that poset underlying ***u***, and for every element of ***w***, all (comparable and) smaller elements are also in ***w***.

Comment: In principle you can trace through a proof of the Urysohn metrization theorem in the context of your particular space and actually construct a compatible metric, but in practice that’s likely to be at best a pretty daunting task. Any other approach, though, is going to depend on the specific space in question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a description of the space I am working with.

Comment: Question edited to define the topology. Thanks.